# How to combine multiple columns of a pandas Dataframe into one column in JSON format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a sample dataframe as follows:

| Main Key | Second | Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | A | Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 | Value 4 | Value 5 |
| Second | B | Value 6 | Value 7 | Value 8 | Value 9 | Value 10 |
| Third | C | Value 11 | Value 12 | Value 13 | Value 14 | Value 15 |
| Fourth | D | Value 16 | Value 17 | Value 18 | Value 19 | Value 20 |

I want to make a new column called 'Aggregated Data', where I make each value in Columns A to E, as key-value pair, and combine them in 'Aggregated Data' in JSON Format

The expected output would look like this:

| Main Key | Second | Aggregated Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | A | {"Column A":"Value 1","Column B":"Value 2","Column C":"Value 3","Column D":"Value 4","Column E":"Value 5"} |
| Second | B | {"Column A":"Value 6","Column B":"Value 7","Column C":"Value 8","Column D":"Value 9","Column E":"Value 10"} |
| Third | C | {"Column A":"Value 11","Column B":"Value 12","Column C":"Value 13","Column D":"Value 14","Column E":"Value 15"} |
| Fourth | D | {"Column A":"Value 16","Column B":"Value 17","Column C":"Value 18","Column D":"Value 19","Column E":"Value 20"} |

Any idea how this can be achieved? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just *skip* the first two columns and call [`to_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) :

```
out = (df[["Main Key", "Second"]]
       .assign(Aggregated_Data= df.iloc[:, 2:]
                                  .apply(lambda x: x.to_json(), axis=1))
```

Alternatively, use a *dict/listcomp* :

```
df["Aggregated_Data"] = [{k: v for k, v in zip(df.columns[2:], v)}
                         for v in df.iloc[:,2:].to_numpy()]
```

Output :

```
print(out)

  Main Key Second                                    Aggregated_Data
0    First      A  {"Column A":"Value 1","Column B":"Value 2","Co...
1   Second      B  {"Column A":"Value 6","Column B":"Value 7","Co...
2    Third      C  {"Column A":"Value 11","Column B":"Value 12","...
3   Fourth      D  {"Column A":"Value 16","Column B":"Value 17","...
```

Answer (score 1):

Via intermediate [`pandas.DataFrame.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) call (with orient `records` to obtain lists like `[{column -> value}, … , {column -> value}]`):

```
df[['Main Key', 'Second']].assign(Aggregated_Data=df.set_index(['Main Key', 'Second']).to_dict(orient='records'))
```

---

```
  Main Key Second                                    Aggregated_Data
0   First      A   {'Column A': 'Value 1 ', 'Column B': 'Value 2 ...
1  Second      B   {'Column A': 'Value 6 ', 'Column B': 'Value 7 ...
2   Third      C   {'Column A': 'Value 11 ', 'Column B': 'Value 1...
3  Fourth      D   {'Column A': 'Value 16 ', 'Column B': 'Value 1...
```